# How to fill na based on mean value based on different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I am using Python code.

I am working on hotels dataset where I have 2 columns. Bedroom and Bathrooms.

| Bathroom | Bedroom |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| Nan | 2 |
| Nan | 3 |

I want to fill nan based on average value from bedroom.

For example bathroom for 2nd last value can be based on average value of bathroom for bedroom = 2 which is 3/2 = 1.5 (based on 2nd and 3rd row)

and likewise for last row, it should be 2 (based on 4th row).

Comment: `df['Bathroom'] = df['Bathroom'].fillna(df.groupby('Bedroom')['Bathroom'].transform('mean'))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @QuangHoang. It works. Any idea if this warning can have any impact.

C:\Users\amanc\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24528/1522999689.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  seattle_list_mod['bathrooms'] = seattle_list_mod['bathrooms'].fillna(seattle_list_mod.groupby(['bedrooms'])['bathrooms'].transform('mean'))

Comment: search SO for the error, there are a lot of questions already. The gist is your dataframe is a slice of a bigger dataframe. You need to make a copy of that slice.